# Creating a Private Cloud for practice

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, openstack

I have two fairly new Dell Inspiron Desktops, which combined have 16 GB RAM and 1 TB HDD.

Initially I wanted to install vCenter or ESXi on them, but after a two day battle, I gave up due to

```
1) graphics buffer issues
2) NIC issues
```

I'm now wondering if there's anything I can do with them in terms of creating a private cloud for practice, i.e. via OpenStack?

OpenStack-Ubuntu requires 7 machines, so I think that's not an option.  Is there a way to utilize both desktops together in some way to create a private cloud?

Distributed Programming is not a strong skill set of mine, so I can't do that, but I'm hoping to utilize those desktops together in a `combined or distributed` capacity for a learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I gave you cluster advice, not cloud advice. Still, you could create virtual machines, as I previously suggested, and then install a cloud platform over them. Would be a fair bit of layering, but if you're just looking to practice, this ought to work.

<strike>How about utilizing the bridging capabilities of the hypervisors you're interested in? You could connect both machines, acting as hypervisors, to a switch (dumb or managed, your choice).</strike>

Once that's done, fire up some virtual machines on each of your Dell boxes. Bridge them to the network interfaces you want to connect to the central switch, and assign some addresses. So long as all the virtual machines are in the same subnet (or, if your switch can do some layer 3 magic, that the subnets are routable) you've now got a cluster of machines for cloud fun.

I've used similar setups, whether virtualized or on discrete hardware, for sandboxing things like CoreOS clusters before actual deployment. Has worked a treat.